# Numpy problem with array size when in for loop

Tags: numpy, padding, valueerror, broadcasting

I've been struggling with this for weeks...The function should load a 2 columns txt files and return a matrix (shape: 135166, 6). However, it keeps giving me:
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (135165,) (135166,)"
It seems that, when into the for loop, an array shrinks from 135166 to 135165 elements!
If needed:[test file uploaded](https://www.sendspace.com/file/lsqq0a).
Thank you a lot!

---

```
import numpy as np

def time_hist(arr):

    delta=arr[1,0]-arr[0,0]
    delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.05,0.01)),2)
    rescale=0.6
    
    time=np.arange(0,delta*(arr[:,1].size+(max(delay_list)/delta).astype(int)),delta)
    arr1=np.pad(arr,(0,(max(delay_list)/delta).astype(int)),'constant', constant_values=(0,0))
    matrix_t_g=np.zeros((arr1[:,1].size,len(delay_list)+1))
    
    matrix_t_g[:,0]=np.hstack(time)
    
    for i,dt in enumerate(delay_list):
        
        arr2=np.pad(arr[:,1],((dt/delta).astype(int),((max(delay_list)-dt)/delta).astype(int)),"constant", constant_values=(0, 0))
        arr3=(arr2+arr1[:,1])/rescale
        matrix_t_g[:,i+1]=np.hstack(arr3)
        
    return matrix_t_g    

arr=np.loadtxt("file.txt")

time_hist(arr)
```

Comment: Gicve us the actual error with traceback (i.e. where!)  Identify which variables give the problem.  Also what is `arr.shape`?

Comment: When faced with dimension errors like this I do a couple of things.  1) test with small arrays, 2) check dimensions, no guesses or 'should-be', 3) pay attention to the traceback.

Comment: `delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.05,0.01)),2)` in this line you will only get 5 values, as 0.05 is not included in the range.

Comment: @hpaulj - 

  File "C:\Users\PROVA.py", line 43, in <module>
    time_hist(arr)

  File "C:\Users\PROVA.py", line 26, in time_hist
    matrix_t_g[:,i+1]=np.hstack((arr2+arr1[:,1])/rescale)

The arr.shape is: (131072, 2)

Comment: @ Michael Sidorov
Yes, true. However, it should not be related to the error.
Is there a better way to include also 0.05? Thank you

Comment: Unbelievable!!...the error only appears up 0.02:

delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.01,0.01)),2) - WORKS FINE
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.02,0.01)),2) - WORKS FINE
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.03,0.01)),2) - DOESN'T WORK
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.04,0.01)),2) - DOESN'T WORK
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.05,0.01)),2) - DOESN'T WORK

Comment: Still Unbelievable!!...the error only appears only for even numebers:

delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.02,0.01)),2) - WORKS FINE
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.03,0.01)),2) - DOESN'T WORK
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.04,0.01)),2) - WORKS FINE
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.05,0.01)),2) - DOESN'T WORK
delay_list=np.round(list(np.arange(0.00,0.06,0.01)),2) - WORKS FINE

AND SO ON...